# How to redirect a deleted subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, apache2

I want to (301) redirect all incoming traffic/links from `blog.example.com` to `wwww.example.com`. The `blog.example.com` subdomain does not exist anymore. How can I do this with the `.htacess` file on `www.example.com`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "subdomain does not exist anymore"? Have you just stopped using it or did you actually delete it from the server configuration? Basically a subdomain is just another web address and can point to anything. There is no relation to the domain except if configured this way. Do you have access to the webserver config? By default you have no influence about anything on a subdomain from the main domain.

Comment: I have access to the webserver. I had 2 websites running: blog.example.com and www.example.com. First I redirected al the links by putting a htacess file in blog.example.com. This worked but it conflicted with my website www.example.com as this uses www.example.com/blog/title-post/ as permalinks. To solve this I deleted the blog.example.com subdomain. However I would like to redirect incoming visitors/links to blog.example.com to www.example.com. Is this possible?

Comment: @KimPiot: See my answer. You need that subdomain, otherwise clients won't be able to contact your webserver. HTTP redirects send whole domains, so you could translate the URLs for blog.example.com into the right URLs for www.example.com.

Answer (score 3):

This is a question better asked on ServerFault.

Anyway: This can't be done without having the domain. Domains are managed by the domain name system (DNS). Redirects are part of HTTP which is something completely different. If there's no longer a domain blog.example.com, the web browser can not resolve the address for it and thus has no way to connect to a HTTP server that could redirect it to www.example.com.

You need a valid DNS entry for blog.example.com otherwise this will not work. In your case you'd use a CNAME entry, i.e. tell the resolving system that www.example.com is the canonical name for blog.example.com. The client will then resolve www.example.com, but connect to the HTTP server with the host header being set to blog.example.com. This allows the HTTP server to answer with a redirect to www.example.com, which the client then can follow.